# Dynamic array in class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a class with member of dynamic array (I posted my code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/y2iyj4ge)) I wonder if my both classes are correct and if there is anything wrong with them? Also how I need to write (41 line) a function that sets class `Student` to `StudentsDynamicArray`?

Here is my array class

```
    class StudentsDynamicArray{
        private:
            Student *Stud;// students dynamic array
            int n; // current size of array
            int nmax; // max size of array
        public:
            StudentsDynamicArray():n(0), Stud(NULL), nmax(0){}
            StudentsDynamicArray(int n):
                    n(n){}
            ~StudentsDynamicArray(); // destructor
            void SetStud(Student S){Stud[n++] = S;} // I get error when I try to set String or Int.    //How I need to change this?
            Student GetStud(int i){return Stud[i];}
            void IncreaseSize(int ns);
        };
//Function which change size of array
void Student::ChangeSize(int kiek){
         if(kiek > nmax){
                 int *SNEW = new int[kiek];
                 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                         SNEW[i] = mark[i];
                 delete [] mark;
                 mark = SNEW;
                 nmax = kiek;
         }
         else if(kiek < nmax){
                 int *SNEW = new int[kiek];
                 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                         SNEW[i] = mark[i];
                 delete [] mark;
                 mark = SNEW;
                 n = nmax = kiek;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Student class you have

```
int *mark
```

this is indication that you must apply [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29): copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor. First two should make a copy of dynamic array, and destructor should free memory. You have only destructor properly implemented. The same applies to StudentsDynamicArray class.

as for:

```
void SetStud(Student S){Stud[n++] = S;}
```

from your code it looks like you have not called IncreaseSize initially, and Stud is possibly NULL once you call SetStud. You can fix it by calling it in constructor:

```
StudentsDynamicArray():n(0), Stud(NULL), nmax(0){ IncreaseSize(10); }
```

---

also, all of the above would not be necessary if you would use std::vector, so if such low lever dynamic arrays are not your requirement then use std::vector. Then you would use [rule of zero](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero).

[edit]

Your copy constructor / assignment operators should like as follows:

```
Student (const Student& other) {
  // here allocate this->mark to be the same size as in other
  // copy values from other.mark to this->mark
  // also copy other values from `other` to this
}

Student& operator= (const Student& other)
{
  // here allocate this->mark to be the same size as in other
  // copy values from other.mark to this->mark
  // also copy other values from `other` to this
  return *this;
}
```

As you can see they are "quite" similar. Wiki on rule of three is actually updated to C++11, where you can add move semantics which increase efficiency of copy by value operations (and actually are known as rule of five). If you are learning basics, you can stay with previous rules.

Comment: marcin_j Thanks for quick reply! As you can see in my code I have written destructor. But how I need to copy constructor? I don't get it. And what is assignment operator? I have never used this thing before.

Comment: You are making copies of Student in your code, like `Stud[n++] = S`, this makes use of operator= (look into the link from my answer), to make such copy correct you need to implement operator= to allocate new dynamic array. Objects in C++ are copied by value, not by reference like in C# or Java.

Comment: Thanks I have made some changes in my post. (Also in pastebin).

Comment: Updated answer with how your constructor and assignment operator should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could better use `std::vector` to wrap the students into a collection. This will dramatically increase performance, and will lead to less errors.

Below is the prototype of classes you can use.

```
class Student
{
private:
  string mName;
  unsigned int mAge;
public:
  Student() : mName(""), mAge(0) {}
  Student( string name, unsigned int age ) : mName(name), mAge(age) {}
  string get_name() const;
  void set_name( string name );
  unsigned int get_age() const;
  void set_age( unsigned int age ); 
};

class Students
{
private: 
  vector<Student> mCollection;
public:
  Students() : mCollection() { }
  Students( vector<Student> &input_collection ) : mCollection( input_collection ) { }
  Students &add_student( Student &s );
  Students &remove_student( Student &s );
  Students &remove_student( string name );
  Students &remove_student( size_t index );
  Students &edit_student( size_t index, string new_name, unsigned int new_age );
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I know that vector is really useful thing. But I  want to learn more about dynamic arrays.